# How to translate this query with Doctrine?

Tags: sql, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, dql

I try to generate a custom query (I'm developing a search engine for a website).

This is te query to translate :

```
SELECT *  FROM `offre_habitation` 
WHERE `id_type_offre` = 2 
AND `id_nature_offre` = 1 
AND (`nb_pieces` = 2 or `nb_pieces` = 1 or `nb_pieces` = 3 or `nb_pieces` = 4)
AND (`id_secteur`=1 OR `id_secteur` = 2 or id_secteur = 3) 
AND `surface_habitable` > 90 
AND `prix` > 700
```

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not tested, but something like this should do the trick:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->select('o.*')
  ->from('offre_habitation o')
  ->where('o.id_type_offre = ?', 2)
  ->andWhere('o.id_nature_offre = ?', 1)
  ->andWhereIn('o.nb_pieces', array(1, 2, 3, 4))
  ->andWhereIn('o.id_secteur', array(1, 2, 3))
  ->andWhere('o.surface_habitable > ?', 90)
  ->andWhere('o.prix > ?', 700);

// Test:
echo $q->getSqlQuery();
```

...this makes use of the fact that, for example:

```
AND (`id_secteur`=1 OR `id_secteur` = 2 or id_secteur = 3)
```

...is the same as:

```
AND `id_secteur` IN (1, 2, 3)
```